# YARN Timeline Server .out file not rotating

Tags: hadoop, logging, hadoop-yarn

Yarn Timeline Server produces logs at  /var/log/hadoop-yarn location. We see two type of log files:

1. `hadoop-yarn-timelineserver-<host_ip>*.log*`
2. `hadoop-yarn-timelineserver-<host_ip>*.out*`

The disk is getting filled due `.out` file growing indefinitely which result into disk full errors.

Any solution to rotate `.out` file or add a size check on the same

Comment: Please show the relevant log4j files for the timeline server process

Comment: As per my understanding, hadoop-yarn-timelineserver-<host_ip>*.log use log4j but not .out file.

Comment: I meant your actual log4j.properties files where the rotating log appender would get setup. Otherwise, there's other logrotate / Cron solutions that have nothing to do with hadoop

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your DataNode and NameNode logs for any "IllegalAccessException" errors? If yes, then the issue you are facing is related to a known Hadoop bug of Jersey 1.9 version. There are temporary solutions such as upgrading to latest version of Jersey.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11461